# Как найти путь к файлу с названием main.py через CLI?

Tags: python, консоль

На сколько я понял CLI - это командная строка.
1. Я установил Git Bash.
2. Создал файл с названием main.py.
Не могу понять как найти путь к этому файлу через CLI и ввести для него команду.

Comment: Вы не знаете где создали файл?

Comment: @insolor Возможно вопрос глупый. Я знаю, где создал файл. Ну я в Git Bash указывал cd d:pythonprojects. Просто в данный момент я читаю небольшую инструкцию и там написано сначала в текстовом редакторе Sublime Text 3 создать файл и написать "print 'Hello!'" и найти путь к файлу через CLI и ввести команду "$ python main.py". После этого должен высветиться текст файла. На сколько я понимаю, текст должен высветиться в Git Bash. Но я пока не понял, как все это сделать..

Answer (score 0):

1. Когда Вы создаёте файл в любом текстовом редакторе, нажмите `Сохранить как`, выберите, куда Вам нужно сохранить файл и запомните это место
2. Сейчас, если Вы создали только один файл `main.py`, можете поискать его по всему компьютеру поиском Windows. Если найдётся несколько, откройте каждый и посмотрите, тот ли это
3. Git bash вряд ли как-то поможет Вам в поиске файла, для этого существует специальный инструмент Windows (см. п. 2)

P.S. CLI – Command Line Interface (интерфейс командной строки) – это не обязательно cmd в Windows. Этот термин используется, в основном, для противопоставления консольного интерфейса графическому. То есть, например, Git bash – это тоже CLI.